# ngRoute in angularjs/multiple views

Tags: angularjs-routing, ngroute

I am following a tutorial for learning angular. I am using ngRoute to marry 2 sets of views/controllers.

customers.html and cutomersController and 
orders.html and ordersController.

When index.html loads it does show customers.html as desired. But when I click on 'View Orders' link, it does not show the order details.

The link for the code: http://plnkr.co/DW2rqiFIkxnhVPPisfLn

here is the code for index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="customersApp">
<head>
<title>Route 2</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-view></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="customersController.js"></script>
<script src="ordersController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here is the code for app.js

```
        var app = angular.module('customersApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'CustomersController',
                templateUrl: 'customers.html'   
            })
            .when('/orders/:customerId', {
                controller: 'OrdersController',
                templateUrl: 'orders.html'  
            })

            .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });

});


here is the code for customersController.js


app.controller('CustomersController', function ($scope){
        $scope.sortBy= 'name';
        $scope.reverse  = false;

        $scope.customers=[
            {
                id: 1, 
                joined: '2000-12-02',
                name:'John', 
                city:'Sacramento', 
                orderTotal:7.554,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id:1,
                        product: 'Shoes',
                        total: 7.554
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id:2,
                joined: '2012-12-07', 
                name:'Tom', 
                city:'Chandler', 
                orderTotal:19.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id:2,
                        product: 'Baseball',
                        total: 9.995
                    },
                    {
                        id:3,
                        product: 'Bat',
                        total: 9.995
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                joined: '1997-05-02', 
                name:'Matt', 
                city:'Michigan', 
                orderTotal:19.993,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:4,
                        product: 'Tiara',
                        total: 19.993
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                joined: '2001-10-08', 
                name:'Jane', 
                city:'New York', 
                orderTotal:112.954,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:5,
                        product: 'Stereo',
                        total: 112.954
                    }
                    ]
            }
            ];

$scope.doSort = function(propName){
            $scope.sortBy = propName;
            $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
        };
});
```

here is the code for OrdersController.js

```
    (function(){
var OrdersController = function ($scope, $routeParams){
        var customerId = $routeParams.customerId;
        $scope.orders = null;

        function init() {
        // Search for the customers for the customer id
        for(var i=0, len=$scope.customers.length; i<len;i++){
            if ($scope.customers[i].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
                $scope.orders = $scope.customers[i].orders;
                break;
                }
            }
        }


        $scope.customers=[
            {
                id: 1, 
                joined: '2000-12-02',
                name:'John', 
                city:'Sacramento', 
                orderTotal:7.554,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id:1,
                        product: 'Shoes',
                        total: 7.554
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id:2,
                joined: '2012-12-07', 
                name:'Tom', 
                city:'Chandler', 
                orderTotal:19.99,
                orders: [
                    {
                        id:2,
                        product: 'Baseball',
                        total: 9.995
                    },
                    {
                        id:3,
                        product: 'Bat',
                        total: 9.995
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                joined: '1997-05-02', 
                name:'Matt', 
                city:'Michigan', 
                orderTotal:19.993,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:4,
                        product: 'Tiara',
                        total: 19.993
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                joined: '2001-10-08', 
                name:'Jane', 
                city:'New York', 
                orderTotal:112.954,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:5,
                        product: 'Stereo',
                        total: 112.954
                    }
                    ]
            }
            ];
            init();
        };

        OrdersController.$inject = ['$scope', '$routeParams'];
        angular.module('customersApp')
            .controller('OrdersController', OrdersController);
}());
```

here is the code for customers.html

```
    <h2>Customers</h2>
Filter: <input type="text" ng-model="customersFilter.name"/>
<br /><br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="doSort('name')">Name</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('city')">City</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('orderTotal')">Order Total</th>
        <th ng-click="doSort('joined')">Joined</th>
    </tr>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:customersFilter | orderBy:sortBy:reverse">
        <td>{{cust.name}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.city}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.orderTotal | currency}}</td>
        <td>{{cust.joined | date:'longDate'}}</td>
        <td><a href="#/orders/{{ cust.id }}">View Orders</a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<br />
<span>Total customers: {{customers.length}}</span>
```

here is the code for orders.html

```
    <h2>Orders</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product></th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="order in orders">
        <td>{{order.product}}</td>
        <td>{{order.total |currency}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so luckily this is a simple fix.
For some reason your JSON is not uniform.
Though these two `customers` have only one order in their order array, the `order` array needs to be renamed to `orders`, for Matt and Jane.

You just need to edit this hard-coded JSON in ordersController.js and it should work.

`{
                id: 3,
                joined: '1997-05-02', 
                name:'Matt', 
                city:'Michigan', 
                orderTotal:19.993,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:4,
                        product: 'Tiara',
                        total: 19.993
                    }
                    ]
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                joined: '2001-10-08', 
                name:'Jane', 
                city:'New York', 
                orderTotal:112.954,
                order:  [
                    {
                        id:5,
                        product: 'Stereo',
                        total: 112.954
                    }
                    ]
            }
            ];`

In the meantime you should edit this loop

        `for(var i=0, len=$scope.customers.length; i<len;i++){
            if ($scope.customers[i].id === parseInt(customerId)) {
                $scope.orders = $scope.customers[i].orders;
                break;
                }
            }
        }`

This is a great place to use the `forEach` method.

    `$scope.customers.forEach(function(customer) {
        if (customer.id === parseInt(customerId) {
            $scope.orders = customer.orders;
        })
    });`

It's a little more modern and a little easier to read.